# How to make my Image move in a random direction?

Tags: java

I have an image that rotating in a counter clockwise direction. Now, I want it to move in a random direction during or whenever it touch the wall. The problem is I can't do it, please help me about this matter.

This is my code :

```
private double x;
private double y;
private double speed;

public void move(long dt)
{
    double dt_s = dt / 1e9;
    double dx = speed * dt_s;
    double dy = speed * dt_s;

    final double right_border = 100;
    final double up_border = 100;
    final double down_border = 0.0;
    final double left_border = 0.0;


    x += dx;

    if (x >= right_border)
    {
        x = right_border;
      if (y >= down_border)
       {               
    y += dy;
       }

    }
    if (y > up_border)
    {
        y = up_border;
        if (x >= left_border)
        {
            speed *= -1;
        }

    }
    if (x <= left_border)
    {
        x = left_border;
        if (y <= up_border)
        {
            y += dy;
        }

    }
    if (y < down_border)
    {
        y = down_border;
        if (x <= right_border)
        {
            speed *= -1;
        }

    }

 }
```

Comment: Do you want a random direction, or do you want it to "bounce" off of the borders?

Comment: Give it a direction in radians and use the trigonometric functions to calculate the delta x and delta y to move a given distance.

Comment: @Nate could you give me some more idea about that? coz i'm a little bit confuse now.

Comment: Do you want the speed to be constant, or can that also change by hitting the border?

Comment: @user995048 just a constant speed

Comment: This might help: http://www.helixsoft.nl/articles/circle/sincos.htm

Comment: @Nate yeah, tnx for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you must solve the problem of your class being directionless - you have speed, but your direction is fixed at 45 degree north east (increment x and y the same).

Add direction to your class as follows:

```
...
private double speed;
private double angle; // in radians - makes math easier

public void move(long dt) {
    ...
    double dx = speed * dt_s * Math.sin(angle);
    double dy = speed * dt_s * Math.cos(angle);
    ...
```

Now to head in a random direction:

```
myObject.setAngle(Math.PI * 2 * Math.random()); // Math.PI * 2 = 360 degrees
```

If hitting a wall, you will have to limit your angle to an angle that's *away* from the wall you are hitting. I'll leave that to you, but it will take the form of:

```
myObject.setAngle(minAngle + ((maxAngle - minAngle) * Math.random()));
```

Comment: Are you kidding? It's a instance of your class! You didn't say what the name of your class is, so I just called it "myObject".

Answer (score 2):

This is one possible solution.

Generate a random point (x,y) on one of the boundaries (other than the boundary that the image just hit), and make the image move towards that point. All you have to do is, find the slope between the point P1(x1,y1) it just hit, and the random point just generated P2(x2,y2). Using the slope you can find the equation of the line, it has to travel in. You're done!!